# list of shorthand css properties

Tags: javascript, css, shorthand

A JavaScript function I made needs to parse all CSS values that don't necessarily have 'one' value attached to them. For example, `margin:0 0 4px 12px;` is actually four values (margin-top, margin-right, etc).

Basically, all I need is a list of the shorthand properties. However, I don't need all shorthand css. I just need the shorthand css that could potentially be animated (rgb, px, em,etc). So, I don't care about `border:1px solid black;` since I can't animate `solid.` But I do care about `border-width,` since border-width is shorthand for all four borders.

Anyways, my list includes:
- border-width
- background-position
- padding
- margin
- border-radius
- box-shadow
- outline-radius
- border-color
- border-colors
- text-shadow
- font

So, did I miss any? You see, I don't know if there are any obscure properties that are like: `mystery-color:red green blue hazel pigbreath;`

Comment: Did you ever get a list of these ?

Comment: The W3C animatable properties list had most, if not all of them (I think). Its linked to in the answer comments.

Answer (score 9):

This is a complete list of all shorthand properties implemented by Firefox, ripped from the source code.  I don't know which of them "could potentially be animated" by your JavaScript.  I've trimmed out the ones that are only shorthand for internal reasons too complicated to get into here.

```
background
border
border-color
border-style
border-width
border-top
border-right
border-bottom
border-left
cue
font
list-style
margin
marker
-moz-border-start
-moz-border-end
-moz-border-radius
-moz-column-rule
-moz-outline-radius
-moz-transition
outline
overflow
padding
pause
```

Comment: I guess saying 'shorthand properties' wasn't quite right. Just properties that have multiple values embedded. Like, background-position or box-shadow. Both of those aren't shorthand, but have multiple values.

Comment: I can't easily extract that from the source code :-/  Maybe this list is of more help? http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties-